# 'Backspace' and 'Clear' functions not working in JavaScript calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

So the title tells most of the story. I am making a pure HTML/CSS/JS calculator and the HTML/CSS went well but I can't seem to get the first couple functions to work. I've already done googling but just comparing code, my code looks like it should work, so I'm stumped. Anyway, here's any potentially relevant code.

```js
var oneBtn = document.getElementById('calc-one');
var twoBtn = document.getElementById('calc-two');
var threeBtn = document.getElementById('calc-three');
var fourBtn = document.getElementById('calc-four');
var fiveBtn = document.getElementById('calc-five');
var sixBtn = document.getElementById('calc-six');
var sevenBtn = document.getElementById('calc-seven');
var eightBtn = document.getElementById('calc-eight');
var nineBtn = document.getElementById('calc-nine');
var zeroBtn = document.getElementById('calc-zero');

var decimalBtn = document.getElementById('calc-decimal');
var clearBtn = document.getElementById('calc-clear');
var backspaceBtn = document.getElementById('calc-backspace');
var displayValElement = document.getElementById('calc-display-val');

var displayVal = '0';
var pendingVal;
var evalStringArray = [];

var calcNumBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('calc-btn-num');
var calcOperatorBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('calc-btn-operator');

var updateDisplayVal = (clickObj) => {
  var btnText = clickObj.target.innerText;

  if (displayVal === '0')
    displayVal = '';

  displayVal += btnText;
  displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
}

for (let i = 0; i < calcNumBtns.length; i++) {
  calcNumBtns[i].addEventListener('click', updateDisplayVal, false);
}
//for (let i = 0; i < calcOperatorBtns.length; i++) {
//    calcOperatorBtns[i].addEventListener('click', performOperation, false)
//}

clearBtn.onClick = () => {
  displayVal = '0';
  pendingVal = undefined;
  evalStringArray = [];
  displayValElement.innerHTML = displayVal;
}

backspaceBtn.onClick = () => {
  let lengthOfDisplayVal = displayVal.length;
  displayVal = displayVal.slice(0, lengthOfDisplayVal - 1);

  if (displayVal === '')
    displayVal = '0';
  displayValElement.innerText = displayVal;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.calc-btn {
  background-color: silver;
  color: black;
  width: 25px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.calc-btn:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.row {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 200px;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
}

#calc-zero {
  width: 52.66666667px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 7px;
}

#calc-clear {
  width: 52.66666667px;
}

#calc-display-val {
  height: 80x;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 48px;
  background-color: #383838;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
}

.calc-btn-operator {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#calc-equals {
  border-radius: 0 0 7px 0;
}

#calc-parent {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Pure HTML/CSS/JS Calculator</h1>

  <div id="calc-parent">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" id="calc-display-val">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="calc-btn column" id="calc-clear">AC</div>
      <div class="calc-btn column" id="calc-backspace">&#8676;</div>
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-operator column" id="calc-divide">&#247;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-num column" id="calc-seven">7</div>
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-num column" id="calc-eight">8</div>
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-num column" id="calc-nine">9</div>
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-operator column" id="calc-multiply">x</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-num column" id="calc-four">4</div>
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-num column" id="calc-five">5</div>
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-num column" id="calc-six">6</div>
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-operator column" id="calc-minus">-</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-num column" id="calc-one">1</div>
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-num column" id="calc-two">2</div>
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-num column" id="calc-three">3</div>
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-operator column" id="calc-plus">+</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-num column" id="calc-zero">0</div>
      <div class="calc-btn column" id="calc-decimal">.</div>
      <div class="calc-btn calc-btn-operator column" id="calc-equals">=</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide the HTML too

Comment: Hi. Please add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (including your css and html) so we can have a better look.

Comment: `element.onClick` is a custom method, it has not a native implementation. Use the regular `addEventListener` to attach the click event to the Backspace and Clear buttons too.

Comment: Also the floating point is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `backspaceBtn.onClick` to `backspaceBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {` should do the trick. I prepared a fiddle for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jhexg32p/).

Answer (score 1):

Using on**c**lick instead of on**C**lick. i.e. lowercase c in onclick will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

At first while using ES6, you should add "Use Strict" at the beginning of your script.

Second ensure the script is run, when the DOM is ready, otherwise getElementById will be undefined, because the element is not rendered yet.

Third you have a typo: try btnBackspace.onclick, which worked on my test. (Using Firefox)

Fourth, might be just here but you forgot the HTML-Tags.